# Finding prime solutions to $100q+80 = p^3 + q^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

Finding prime solutions to $100q+80 = p^3 + q^2$

Does them being prime imply some patterns on division modulo 3 or some other integer? How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solving your equation for $q$ we obtain
$q=50\pm\sqrt{2580-p^3}$
we get
$p\le 13$
therefore $p\in \{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$

Answer (score 4):

**Outline:** One can do it crudely. Rewrite the equation as $-p^3=q^2-100q-80$, and note that the smallest value of $q^2-100q-80$ is $-2580$.

Comment: by grind it out you mean to check all those values?

Comment: Yes, there are very few primes $p$ whose cube is less than $2580$.

Comment: oh ok looks cool